# Symfony2: Call a Controller /File on EVERY action

Tags: php, javascript, service, symfony, controller

I'm doing a huge project with Symfony2. Frontend is javascript/html5 canvas. For site changes I use ajax requests.

Now I want to call a php file which should be executed with EVERY user action. Is there an elegant way to do so?

For better understanding: I'm doing some kind of game and the php checks, if something happend (recruitments done, buildings finished etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [JMSAopBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but is there another solution without using an extra bundle?

Comment: If your code is not dependent on controller action then you can create an event listener for `kernel.request` or `kernel.response` event and execute the code there.

Answer (score 0):

If by user action you mean executing a controller action (i.e. server side), what I would do is listen to the kernel.controller event: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html

so you can load your script and execute it juste before the target controller is invoked

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();
    //...
    // call your php file here

    // the controller can be changed to any PHP callable
    $event->setController($controller);
}
```

I don't think you even need to modify the controller so you can remove the first and last line...

Comment: There is a more detailed description of this method here http://matt.drollette.com/2012/06/calling-a-method-before-every-controller-action-in-symfony2/

Comment: @MDrollette Your URL is `404 Not Found`.